# Exception handling doesn't work with Qt on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, exception, qt4, mingw

I'm facing strange problem. Namely, Qt somehow turns off exception handling in my program. I can't catch any exception, and when I throw an exception application crashes.

I'm using Qt 4.7.0 (32 bit) from Qt SDK v2010.05 on Windows 7 (64 bit), g++ (GCC) 4.5.1 from MinGW, NetBeans 6.9.1.
But I also cheked this with g++ 3.4.5 (also from MinGW) and Qt Creator 2.0.1 - same strange behavior.

For example (simplest case):

```
#include <Qt/QApplication.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    try {
        cout << "Before exception" << endl;
        throw runtime_error("Exception occured");
        cout << "After exception" << endl;
    } catch (runtime_error& exc) {
        cout << exc.what() << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I execute above program I've got this output:

> Before exception
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
>   Please contact the application's support team for more information.

I've tried to add flag "-fexceptions" to g++ but it hasn't changed anything.

When I don't use Qt, everything is OK:

```
#include <Qt/QApplication.h> // It is not caused only by including Qt header
                             // so it doesn't matter if I comment this out or not
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // QApplication app(argc, argv);

    try {
        cout << "Before exception" << endl;
        throw runtime_error("Exception occured");
        cout << "After exception" << endl;
    } catch (runtime_error& exc) {
        cout << exc.what() << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

> Before exception
>   Exception occured

Does anybody know why is this happen that way and how to fix this? Has it something to do with type of exception handling method (SJLJ or Dwarf-2) used when Qt was build?

Comment: Whew, you scared me!  We're probably about to switch to Qt on my recommendation and this would have been a killer.  Good thing it works with VS.

Comment: Where does it crash exactly? Any chance you can find a more exact location? QApplication's notify() perhaps?

Comment: probably it's configured with the `-no-exceptions` flag. Try to reconfigure and re-make the Qt SDK.

Comment: Hmm, this is *verbatim* a Microsoft CRT message.  Does mingw emulate it *that* well?  Doubtful and probably the reason for this problem.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Mingw links against MSVCRT.

Comment: Encountered the same problem, but for now no solution works for me. Although I believe **revers** pointed out to the right solution, I cannot make it work, yet. 

I've recompiled the Qt twice with no success by now. Which version of MinGW and compilers do you use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've reconfigured and recompiled Qt with flag `-exceptions`:
   `D:\Qt\2010.05\qt>mingw32-make confclean && configure -exceptions && mingw32-make`
and now everything is ok!

Thanks all for help, especially to Nick D!

Anyway, it's very strange that I had Qt build without this flag. I had downloaded Qt SDK in binary form from official site.

Answer (score 0):

It's no longer necessary to use the -exceptions flag with Qt. In Qt Creator 4 it's the default, and my Windows Qt app happily uses vast and extensive exception handling with no problems. Qt MSVC builds use the /EHsc compiler option, which turns normal exception handling on.