# Are all official Qt binaries built with -no-exceptions?

Tags: c++, qt, exception

If I write

```
try {
    throw std::exception("Exception");
} catch (std::exception& ex) {
    qDebug("Game Over");
}
```

inside my main function (or anywhere else), my Qt application crashes.
This effect has been described (5 years ago) in [Exception handling doesn't work with Qt on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149118/exception-handling-doesnt-work-with-qt-on-windows).

The original poster apparently solved the problem by reconfiguring and rebuilding the Qt SDK himself (explicitly enabling `-exceptions`), but I have a hard time believing that all Qt binaries are shipped with exceptions turned off and that everyone using exceptions must do this.

Could anyone point me to the place where this is documented, tell me whether this is true at all or what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm now on Qt 5.4.2 with MSVC2013, Win 7 (downloaded qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013_opengl-5.4.2.exe from [here](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.4/5.4.2/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013_opengl-5.4.2.exe)).

Comment: That should not even compile, `std::exception` does not have a constructor that accepts `const char*` arguments. `std::exception` is only meant to be used as a base class for the acutal exceptions. Try e.g. `throw std::runtime_error("Exception");` instead.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I see. I don't get any build errors though. What does that tell me? Besides, it's not about this specific exception, but exceptions thrown by a 3rd party lib, that I need to catch. Any idea about that?

Comment: *"What does that tell me?"* Apparently your standard library implementation offers non standard features. *"Any idea about that?"* No, I can't answer this question, I never used QT. The above was just an OT remark and not meant as an answer. That's why I posted it as a comment and not as an answer. :)

Comment: @BaummitAugen this is an MSVC extension.

Answer (score 3):

You're not doing anything wrong. Since Qt doesn't use exceptions, it'd be unnecessary overhead to have them enabled in the default Qt builds. Hence, on platforms that allow the exceptions to be disabled, they do in fact get disabled.

Generally speaking, you really need to compile Qt yourself. The prebuilt binaries are fine for exploration and student use, but if you're serious about using it in your product, or you need non-default configuration, you absolutely have to compile it yourself with the flags that you need.

Comment: But shouldn't this be indicated clearly for their binary releases then? Is there a site describing the compiler and config options used for the released binaries?

Comment: @virt Perhaps the released binaries come with a configuration dot file? I don't remember whether they do, but do check if there are any files with names that start with a dot. If there are, one of them should be the retained configuration passed to `configure` used in the original build. The binary releases are a bit of a misnomer IMHO, because the product is the source repository, not binaries.